# Binding DropDownList to an Enumeration

Tags: asp.net

How do i bind a regular asp.net dropdownlist to an enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page explains it well:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203182141/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/jawad/archive/2005/06/24/EnumDropDown.aspx)